# Bcrypt docker passwd using --admin-passwd

Tags: bcrypt, portainer

What is wrong with the following command? It is intended to create a portainer container with admin passwd 'portainer':

```
docker run --rm -d --name "portainer" -p "127.0.0.1:9001:9000" -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v portainer_data:/data portainer/portainer --admin-password='$2a$10$0PW6gPY0TSeYzry2RSakl.7VUVmzdmD6mQPcemiG6i2vfJGGGePYu'
```

It leads to a Portainer container that will deny access for 'admin', saying that passwd 'portainer' is invalid. Details:

- I put it into a .bat file. The thing runs on docker CE in Windows 10.
- The longish crypt string within single quotes is a bcrypt equivalent of 'portainer', the designated admin password. I created and checked it here: https://www.javainuse.com/onlineBcrypt
- Prior to running the command I stopped and removed an old portainer container, and even said `docker volume rm portainer_data`.
- Doubling the "$" to "$$" did not solve the issue.
- The command is deeply inspired by the official portainer docs: https://documentation.portainer.io/v2.0/deploy/initial/

For now I have a simple workaround: Simply drop that `--admin-passwd` parameter. Given that I grant a volume to portainer, I can just define a passwd at first start. However, I'd still prefer the script-only solution. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Here it is the solution you need:

```
docker run --detach \
        --name=portainer-ce \
        -p 8000:8000 \
        -p 9000:9000 \
        --restart=always \
        -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
        -v /volume1/docker/portainer-ce:/data \
        portainer/portainer-ce \
        --admin-password="$(htpasswd -nb -B admin adminpwPC | cut -d ':' -f 2)"
```

Comment: Thx. However, this is about the same as my own approach. htpasswd simply adds the hazard of putting the passwd into the command line as plain text. By now I found, that the passwd may be set during first start and is kept in the volume later on. That serves my purpose sufficiently.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).